# libtiff 4.0.10 is blocked by the antivirus that i cannot disable on my company laptop

Tags: miniconda, libtiff

I have installed miniconda and trying to install dask. This installs libtiff 4.0.10 and this is blocked by my antivirus. I cannot disable my antivirus. What can be a possible workaround.

Comment: Talk to your sysadmin?

Comment: Yes, the company laptop does not allow the antivirus to be disabled.

Comment: This issue is resolved now and McAfee does not consider it as a threat